# Compare and synchronize file contents/directories between two servers

Tags: winscp

Suppose I have 3 computers - A, B and C.

Computer A is the deployment server.
Computer B and C are belong to developers.

What is the best way to transfer source codes from B/C to A.
The best tools we found so far is using WinSCP Synchronize feature but this feature only compare files/directories by modification date.

We expect to compare any changes in the file content.

Comment: Are your developers already using a version control system (e.g. Git or SVN or Plastic), and if not, then why not?

Comment: At the moment we don't have admin rights on Computer A and it is not belong to us. We can only transfer files using WinSCP/Filezilla. Only computer A can push to customer Git repository. But we can request new software to be installed if necessary.

Comment: So you have only SFTP access to the A atm?